# Constructing a location from a string

Tags: rascal

I receive the following string to my webserver: `"|project://Detector/src/exporter.rsc|(1762,28,<45,10>,<45,38>)"`
using the `toLocation()` function to convert this to a location will result into an MalFormedURI error.

I can use the `toLocation()` function to convert the string `loc myLoc = toLocation("project://Detector/src/exporter.rsc");` to a location.
With a regular expression I can extract `"0,10,<2,0>,<4,10>"`.
But now the problem is I can do: `myLoc(0,10,<2,0>,<4,10>)`, but I can't do `myLoc("0,10,<2,0>,<4,10>")`. I could extract all this position data with regular expressions and then add it to the location but that will result in nasty code.

What is the best practice in converting a string with position data eg. `"|project://Detector/src/exporter.rsc|(1762,28,<45,10>,<45,38>)"` to a location containing position data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most robust way is this:

```
import ValueIO;
str theString = "|project://Detector/src/exporter.rsc|(1762,28,\<45,10\>,\<45,38\>)";
theLoc = readTextValueString(#loc, theString);
```

The function may throw parse errors which you can catch and handle but I'm guessing that's not going to happen with your setup.